# How to set the color of header and footer of an plain UITableView and remove unnecessary separate lines? 

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In my application, when I drag a table view of plain style up and down, the color of its header and footer portions is white. I'd like to change it to another color. And why there are multiple separate lines even when the table view has only a single row? I need separate lines only for actual data and let rest of the screen without data displays background color. I use a subclass of `UITableViewController` to manage this view. What I want to accomplish is like the picture.

[image] -->[image]

All I want to do is like left side of the split view in the iPad Settings application.

Comment: The image you've shown is a grouped-table-view and the problems you've mentioned are plain-table-view's.

Comment: @EmptyStack: Grouped and plain table views work differently in this case?

Comment: As one can see in you image, the grouped tableView doesn't have white areas above and beneath the table. Plain tables do.

Comment: @Stephen Hsu, Yes. They do behave differently in case of backgrounds and separators.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for both grouped and plain TableViews: You could insert subviews at the top and bottom of your `UITableView`:

```
UIView* myHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f,-50.0f,
                                tableView.contentSize.width,70.0f )];
myHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];    
[tableView addSubview:myHeaderView];
```

The footer would obviously work the same, use `tableView.contentSize.height`, to place it. Of course, you could also use your own subclass of `UIView` in order to create more complex headers and footers. Just avoid too many transparent views if you can for they might have a big impact on your performance.

Comment: Thanks. Do -50.0f and 70.0f have any specific meaning?

Comment: No, you can change them however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Following reference should be helpful to you:
http://www.purplehazeapps.com/home/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=84:headerfooterinuitableview&catid=37:myblog&Itemid=171

Comment: Thanks. But the height of the tableHeaderView needs to be somewhat arbitrary. I cannot restrict how the user drag the table view.

Comment: It's fine, you do not need to restrict user to a height. You can set the frame of label as the height of section you want to set for table view section. The above code you will be using in the cellfortableviewforrowatindexpath, there you can get the height exactly.